# Active CSS property until window resize?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to this so i'm sorry if it is an obvious one. I have two independently scrolling columns like this example here (imagine they work when there is enough content):

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36510/) might make it a bit easier to visualize than the code snippet below

```css
.xo-scroll-col {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-compat/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 xo-scroll-col">
            one
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 xo-scroll-col">
            two
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Once you resize the window enough, the "one" and "two" will stack on top of each other. I would like to have the "xo-scroll-col" css active until they stack, and then disable it.

Basically the idea here is to have them scrolling independently until they are stack as it is no longer needed at that point. Thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Use a media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have mad a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1jzwwm1/) for you. Please check if this is what you need. Mainly two changes made in it.

1) First, height unit changed from `%` to `vh` 
`height: calc(100vh - 120px);`

2) Second, added `media-query` for Bootstrap `md` size

```
@media (min-width:992px){
  .xo-scroll-col {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `$(window).resize` and inside of it listen to `$(window).width()` and then use `.addClass` and `.removeClass()` OR
put your `.xo-scroll-col` class inside of a `@media (max-width: $media-sm){}`.

Read more about Media query in CSS: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries